# Excel vba for each range and split problem

Tags: excel, vba

Please help to solve my problem.
I use below script but result nothing on activesheet..

```
 Sub Dutylist()
 Dim dutyTable(1 To 2, 1 To 4) As String
 Dim Cyc As Integer, Team As Integer
 Dim Svalue As Range, Srange As Range
 Dim Result() As String
 //Cycle 1
 dutyTable(1, 1) = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G"
 dutyTable(1, 2) = "D,C,A,B,A,E,D"
 dutyTable(1, 3) = "B,A,E,C,B,D,E"
 dutyTable(1, 4) = "C,B,C,D,C,A,A"
 //Cycle 2
 dutyTable(2, 1) = "B,E,D,A,D,B,A"
 dutyTable(2, 2) = "B,A,E,C,C,D,B"
 dutyTable(2, 3) = "D,C,A,B,B,E,B"
 dutyTable(2, 4) = "E,A,B,D,A,C,D"

 Cyc = 1
 Set Srange = ActiveSheet.Range("a:a")
 For Team = 1 To 4
      Result = Split(dutyTable(Cyc, Team), ",")
    For Each Svalue In Srange
       If Svalue = "Team " & CStr(Team) Then
          Svalue.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, UBound(Result) + 1).Value = Result
       End If
    Next Svalue
 Next Team
 End Sub
```

Any problem of my code above?

Comment: Works for me when you actually have values like `Team 1` etc. in column "A:A". But you may want to optimise your loop, for each value from 1-4 you are now literally looping through each cell in the whole column >>>>> Super Slow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding for your code execution should be as following, what I have changed is rearrange the `Looping` with some modification and also you should `set range` by reference to **last used row** instead of `A:A` to speed up the execution.

Basically the code will match the value on `Col A` for the Team, if found then return `dutyTable1` value based on the `cycle` give by you,

```
 Sub Dutylist()
 Dim dutyTable(1 To 2, 1 To 4) As String
 Dim Cyc As Integer, Team As Integer
 Dim Svalue As Range, Srange As Range
 Dim Result() As String
 Dim i As Long

 dutyTable(1, 1) = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G"
 dutyTable(1, 2) = "D,C,A,B,A,E,D"
 dutyTable(1, 3) = "B,A,E,C,B,D,E"
 dutyTable(1, 4) = "C,B,C,D,C,A,A"

 dutyTable(2, 1) = "B,E,D,A,D,B,A"
 dutyTable(2, 2) = "B,A,E,C,C,D,B"
 dutyTable(2, 3) = "D,C,A,B,B,E,B"
 dutyTable(2, 4) = "E,A,B,D,A,C,D"

 Cyc = 1
 Set Srange = ActiveSheet.Range("a1:a20")

For Each Svalue In Srange
    For Team = 1 To 4
        Result = Split(dutyTable(Cyc, Team), ",")
            If InStr(Svalue.Value, Team) > 0 Then
               Svalue.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, UBound(Result) + 1).Value = Result
            End If
    Next Team
Next Svalue

 End Sub
```

**Output** (Only 3 Team are tested, can be extended)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replied and helped.  My code is search and find "Team 1","Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4" from activesheet, and export the working shift to the right Team

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RWQfwzbNcE-A01IMAz6F_fzeldFWr-pr/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: How come you result are not match to any table you create, I can't understand the logic behind...For example, how you get `B,C,A,E...` for team 1?

Comment: Sorry of my bad english and your patient.  I mean every week i have to run a new cycle for both 4 teams with the preset working shift each day of the week. Find "team 1"  location and  output the array table dutytable(1,1) values for it.  Then Find "Team 2" and use array dutyable(1,2) values on sheet, And the other Teams do the same procedures as well.  If next week i will use the cycle 2 array dutytable(2,1)....... And i can set 5 more array dutytable on my program.

Comment: Check my edited answer, if you write `Team 1` will work also, accept the answer if helping :)

Comment: Thank you Kin Siang for your big help, it really works for me.

Comment: Welcome, as long as it helping you :)

Comment: I think it will speed up a little the search if change to strRev() "   InStrRev(Svalue.Value, Team) > 0 "

Comment: Ya, you may try, it is just a basic solution for your cases. As long as you feel it is faster.